# Call function while looping through an external file

Tags: python, function, file, call, readfile

I have a function, in this case a function which says if a list with numbers forms an arithmetic progression.

```
def arithmetic(l):
a = li[1] - li[0]
for index in range(len(li) - 1):
    if not (li[index + 1] - li[index] == a):
         return False
return True
```

My problem is now that I have a .txt file like the following:

```
1 2 3 4
10 12 54 33
9 4 24 1
14 15 16 17
```

How can I use my function to go through the file and see if a list/ line forms an arithmetic progression?
I know how to open a file and read it but what is the next step and where can I call my function?

```
fileWithLists = open(input("File name: "))   
rows = filename.readlines()
```

The output should be for the first and second line

```
1 2 3 4 True
10 12 54 33 False
```

and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, correct your function, so it actually uses the given argument by its name.
Second, correct your filename assignment.
Third:

```
for r in rows:
   print (r.strip(), arithmetic([int(i) for i in r.split()]))
```

Comment: This is a pretty good answer tho You could have maybe explained those other issues in code, anyways, I just couldn't pass without mentioning that there is no need for that space between `print` and brackets (it is just tripping me off but You can leave it as You wish)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It was just perfect for me and solved my issue. You are of course right that the function wasn't written good and yes, I correct the function